# Wildfly 8.1 keeps connection open

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wildfly

I have a wildfly 8.1 server on Ubuntu 14.04. It provides data for mobile apps. But i have a problem. After 3900 - 4000 connections it stops working suddenly. Till restart.

Server has 5 min keep time. And i cant set it lower.

My question is there any way to increase that numbers? I have ram and cpu.

I gave **-Xms2g -Xmx6g -XX:MaxPermSize=6g**

I set **always-set-keep-alive="false"** and **tcp-keep-alive="false"** for https-listener.

Comment: Probably your problem is connected with this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3536

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to WildFly 8.2.1 or newer. 
This was known issue in 8.0 & 8.1.

As @rsc pointed out this is one of the issues https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3536 
but not only one, related to this.